# trivial solutions for Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

Let $K$ be an odd degree number field. Consider the Diophantine equation:
$$
X^4 + bY^4 =Z^2
$$ 
where $b\neq 0$.
Say we know that the above equation has only trivial roots in $K$ (for some fixed value of $b$). If $d\in K\setminus K^2$, when does $X^4 + d^2b Y^4=Z^2$ have only trivial roots in $K$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024189

Comment: Could you clarify what you count as trivial roots?

Comment: By non-trivial roots we mean, $XYZ\neq 0$

Comment: Isn't one the quadratic twist of the other by $\sqrt{d}$? If so, I doubt you can say much, the twist could have positive rank or rank 0....

Comment: Precisely, I was wondering if some twists are known to preserve ranks?

Comment: Please don't post nigh-simultaneously on math.stackexchange and math.overflow. The latter is for research level questions; if you are unsure of the level, post in math.stackexchange first, and *give it time*. Only after you have waited sufficiently and received no reply would posting here be appropriate, and you should include in both sites a link to the question in the other to ensure there is no duplication of effort. One and a half hours is not a long enough wait.

Comment: Quadratic twists do not preserve ranks and you will find plenty of literature on the distribution of ranks in twist families.